# Web SQL query from file not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, file

I am having trouble creating a table from an sql file while using the transaction.executeSql() method. My problem is that it doesn't execute the query if the text string comes from the file, but it does when the text string is written in the code. Here is my code:

```
        var db = window.openDatabase('dbtest', '1.0', 'my db test', 1*1024*1024); 

        var lines = rawTable.split('\n'); //text from an ".sql" file
        for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){                

            var sql=lines[i]; //this doesn't work (why?)
            //var sql='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hijos`;'; //and this works (why?)

            if(lines[i])
            {
                console.log(sql);
                db.transaction(function (t) {
                t.executeSql(sql,[], 
                function(tx,results){console.log("Success");},
                function(tx,error){console.log("Failure");});
                });
            }

        } //for
```

Here is my console.log message when it reads the file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Hijos`;
CREATE TABLE `Hijos` (`Padre` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,`Madre` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,`Hijos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL);
INSERT INTO `Hijos` (`Padre`, `Madre`, `Hijos`)VALUES ("Armando","Claudia",3);
INSERT INTO `Hijos` (`Padre`, `Madre`, `Hijos`)VALUES ("Miguel","Norma",2);
INSERT INTO `Hijos` (`Padre`, `Madre`, `Hijos`)VALUES ("Lorenzo","Petra",4);
(5) Failure
```

No other error messages but my logs.
Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I have no trouble executing line by line in the code, but that is not my goal, I want to be able to create a db from a file

Comment: Where you log 'Failure', log the error passed in too and we know more. And brace each logged sql in some markers to see the exact content. And where does the `(5)` come from?